# string.format error

Tags: c#, string.format

I've been searching the internet with the string.format for my code and it seems that I can't find the right one that looks like on my code.

```
DataColumn dtCol;
dtCol = new DataColumn("ImagePath", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
dtImages.Columns.Add(dtCol);
dtImages.Columns["ImagePath"].Expression = string.Format("<a href=\"'{0}'+ImageFilename\">View Image</a>", ImageDownloadPath);
```

(the ImageFilename is a column on my database table)
the above code always throws an error of
"Syntax error: Missing operand before '<' operator"

How do I do this properly?

Comment: You increase your chances of getting an answer if you make the question title more specific.

Comment: What is the desired output of the raw html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for helping me out. I was able to figure out the way to do it. Thanks for all the posts.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try the following?

```
string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\\{1}\">View Image</a>", ImageDownloadPath, ImageFilename);
```

In your code you are using `'`'s around the string format identifier, which would have then shown up in your formatted string, and the `ImageFilename` property was not being used correctly. It would have simply been added as plain text.

The result of your string with the following values would be as such:

```
ImageFilename = "1.jpg";
ImageDownloadPath = "http://www.downloadme.com/images";

Yours: <a href="'http://www.downloadme.com/images'+ImageFilename">View Image</a>
Mine: <a href="http://www.downloadme.com/images/1.jpg">View Image</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not at all clear from the question, but I believe the problem isn't a *compile-time* one at all... not indeed one with `string.Format`. It's a problem with `DataColumn.Expression`. You're giving an expression which includes angle brackets, so it thinks you're trying to perform comparisons.

I can't say I know much about `DataColumn.Expression`, but you should look into how it quotes strings... and how it quotes quotes within strings! For example, this *might* work:

```
dtCol.Expression = string.Format
    ("'<a href=\"{0}'+ImageFilename+'\">View Image</a>'", 
     ImageDownloadPath);
```

However, I think it's likely to make your life a *lot* simpler if you didn't try to compute the HTML in the expression to start with. Can you really not apply processing any later?

Comment: hi Jo,

I've tried your code and it's working. However it is displaying the
 <a href="http://localhost/mhercks/mhercksImageGallery/images/"1.jpg">View Image</a>

What i want to happen is make a hyper link "View Image" not the whole <a href=""> </a> tag in my gridview column

Comment: @nhoyti: Well that's up to how you *use* your datatable. As I said, I don't think this is the most appropriate way of doing things anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dtImages.Columns["ImagePath"].Expression = 
string.Format("&lt;a href=\"'{0}'+ImageFilename\"&gt;View Image&lt;/a&gt;", ImageDownloadPath);
```

Im pretty sure the < and > are trying to be interpreted as part of the expression.